# How can I preserve line breaks in PEM file, using NodeJS to pull it into my application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Using NodeJS, I am pulling a PEM file into my application. The file lives in AWS S3 and in my local environment. When I run the application locally, all is well. But, when I run it on EC2, I get the following error:

> Error: Invalid private key string, must include line breaks

I am using [AWS CloudFront URL Signature Utility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cloudfront-sign)

Here is my function:

```
    function createSignedCookie(domain){

        // we need the domain
        if (!domain) {
            return false;
        }

        const cookieLifeSpan = 900000; // milliseconds, is equal to 15 mins
        const expires = new Date().getTime() + cookieLifeSpan;
        const keyPairId = config.accessKeyId;
        const keyPath = config.pemFilePath;

        const options = {expireTime: expires, keypairId: keyPairId, privateKeyPath: keyPath}

        const signedCookies = cfsign.getSignedCookies(domain + '/*', options);

        return signedCookies;
    }
```

I tried adding \n at the end of each line of the PEM, but that did not solve it.
I also tried adding \r at the end of each line of the PEM, but that did not solve it.
I looked at [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=875217&tstart=0) but it didn't help

Here is `getSignedCookies` method:

```
function getSignedCookies(cfUrl, params){
  var privateKey = _getPrivateKey(params);
  var policy = _createPolicy(
    cfUrl, _getExpireTime(params), _getIpRange(params));
  var signature = _createPolicySignature(policy, privateKey);
  var policyStr = new Buffer(policy.toJSON()).toString('base64');

  var cookies = {};
  cookies['CloudFront-Policy'] = normalizeBase64(policyStr);
  cookies['CloudFront-Signature'] = normalizeBase64(signature);
  cookies['CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id'] = params.keypairId;

  return cookies;
}
```

And here is the`_privateKey` method

```
function _getPrivateKey(params) {
  var privateKeyString = params.privateKeyString;
  var pem;

  if (params.privateKeyPath) {
    pem = fs.readFileSync(params.privateKeyPath);

    privateKeyString = pem.toString('ascii');
    console.log(privateKeyString);
  }

  var newLinePattern = /\r|\n/;
  var lineBreakExists = newLinePattern.test(privateKeyString);
  if (!lineBreakExists) {
      throw new Error('Invalid private key string, must include line breaks');
  }

  return privateKeyString;
}
```

Both of the above methods ship with [AWS CloudFront URL Signature Utility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cloudfront-sign)

Comment: How do you read the PEM file inside `getSignedCookies()` method?

Comment: @Keerthivasan pleaser see update

Comment: do you see line breaks while logging in console?

Comment: @Keerthivasan yes

Comment: Found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Just replace \n before use the value:

```
var private_value = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
console.log(private_value);
```